# Django - Set up a none periodic job?

Tags: python, django, scheduled-tasks

I am working on a django website with an auction system.

The admin inputs the time of the end of each auction and I want to schedule a job at that time.

I have seen a lot of options for periodic jobs like celery but I don't think that it fits my problem.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Did the answer solve your problem? If so please select the answer. If not please provide more information so I can try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a  [Custom Management Command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/#howto-custom-management-commands) In this fashion you could check every minute for ending auctions and kick off your batches as a result of the check.

Comment: Thanks I'll try that !